# Angular & Firebase: Redirect user when the password has been changed

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- I have an account screen / angular component
- On this screen i can change the email address and request for a password reset
- The password reset email works and the password is changed
- Once the password has been changed, I would like to automatically return the user to the login screen

**Questions**

1. How can I detect the password change, listen out for it and act accordingly? In this instance, redirect to the login page?
2. In my Auth Guard, is it possible to have a url check whereby it checks if the current URL is the login page, if it is and the user is signed in, navigate to the 'projects' page. If they aren't signed in, remain on the login page?

**My Password reset method**

```js
// Reset the users password by sending them a password reset email
  sendPasswordReset() {
    var auth = firebase.auth();
    var emailAddress = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;

    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress).then( () => {
      this.passwordEmailSent = true;

    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error['code']);
      alert(ErroAuthEn.convertMessage(error['code']));
    });

  }
```

**My Auth Guard**

This is all I have in my auth service at the moment.

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
return this.auth.authState
    .take(1)
    .map(authState => !!authState)
    .do(auth => !auth ? this.router.navigate(['/login']) : true);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.